# Validate many objects at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model

Let's say I have a model called `SchoolYear`. This model has many periods. When I want create an evaluation structure, it automatically creates three periods with default values.

```
class SchoolYear < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :periods, :dependent => :destroy

  ...

end
```

Later on, I have a view in which the user can update all of these 3 periods, along with the school year (the form is based on the school year). A period has a status field, which may be active, inactive or finished. When the school year is created, the default value for its period's status is inactive

```
class Period < ActiveRecord::Base

  ACTIVE = 1
  INACTIVE = 2
  FINISHED = 3

  belongs_to :school_year

  validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => [ACTIVE, INACTIVE, FINISHED]

end
```

At least one of the periods for the school year needs to have an active status when updating the school year. How can I validate this? If I try to do this in the `SchoolYear` model, all its periods will still have the default values. In the `Period` model, only the current period (`self`) has its new values. When examining the other periods, they all have the default values. They do get updated, but what I mean is that when I try to validate what I want, they still present their old values because they still haven't been updated in the database, and Rails isn't looking for their values in memory.

For example, if I want to do this validation in the `SchoolYear` model, I may have something like this:

```
class SchoolYear < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :at_least_one_active_period, :on => :update

  def at_least_one_active_period
    self.errors.add(:periods_error, "Period Error") unless self.periods.where(:status => Period::ACTIVE).count == 1
  end

end
```

end

This doesn't work out because, as I said, Rails retrieves these values directly from the database, and doesn't take into account what has been passed by the form. Can you help me? Thanks!